# SqlException in Asp.net - Incorrect syntax near 'Van'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have problem with my SqlCommand everything I open the page I get the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Van'.
```

I cannot find the problem because 'Van' is only found once in the entire project, and in the title.. 
This is my code in the Page_Load:

```
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DatabaseConnectionString")))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (SELECT Memo_ID, Dep_Name FROM Department WHERE (Department_ID = Staff.Depar_ID)) AS DepartmentName FROM Staff WHERE (FirstName + SPACE(1) + LastName = " + User.Identity.Name, con);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {

                    String result = sqlReader.GetString(0);
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                    DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(result).Selected = true;
                    //Fill some data like : string result = sqlReader("SomeFieldName");
                }
                sqlReader.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
```

The database connectionstring is correct because it works for all my other pages.. i'm trying to get the department where an employee works so he/she can only view memo's from their own department.

Comment: There is problem in your select query. put a break point and copy the query and try running it in sql server query browser

Comment: Don't build queries like this - you are vulnerable to SQL injection. See [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Sorry.. i'm officially an idiot.. Thanks for helping, it works now :) the Query was indeed wrong and I will not write my queries like that anymore! :) SORRY! But I was just testing it .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the parentheses after the last name provided.

```
SELECT (SELECT Memo_ID, Dep_Name FROM Department 
WHERE (Department_ID = Staff.Depar_ID)) AS DepartmentName 
FROM Staff WHERE (FirstName + SPACE(1) + LastName = 'xxx' )
```

Here is what it should look like:

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DatabaseConnectionString")))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (SELECT Memo_ID, Dep_Name FROM Department WHERE (Department_ID = Staff.Depar_ID)) AS DepartmentName FROM Staff WHERE (FirstName + SPACE(1) + LastName = '" + User.Identity.Name + "')", con);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {

                String result = sqlReader.GetString(0);
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(result).Selected = true;
                //Fill some data like : string result = sqlReader("SomeFieldName");
            }
            sqlReader.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the last name.  You probably want to convert to a parameterized query too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have expected your `WHERE` clause to wrap the `User.Identity.Name` in quotes:

```
WHERE (FirstName + SPACE(1) + LastName = '" + User.Identity.Name + "'" ...
```

Could "*van*" be in the username?

This isn't a very secure query either - but SQL injection's another issue!

Comment: I will take care of the SQL injection, no problem ;)